# Galaxy S4 Turning on problem

Tags: battery

My lock button was having some problems such as when I clicked it it wouldn't do anything or it would glitch and hold down, so I restarted my phone now nothing is happening, I can't get anything on the screen to work at all
I tried to boot into savemode, and download mode, dev move, nothing is working. I tried taking out the battery then trying, still didn't work. The most I can do is have it show "Samsung Custom" and then turn back off.

Comment: I have same problem, and I formatted my mobile, still problem not solved

Comment: I suggest to report to nearest Customer Care in case this device is in warranty.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it was my lock button, I put on my otterbox then banged my lock button against my table fairly hard, but if you don't have a good case I don't recommend that because it would probably crack your phone. use your wrist